# monterey: DMG files not mounting, Could not mount "xxx" (com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter error -119930872)

Tags: macos

When I double click the `anki-2.1.54-mac-intel-qt6.dmg` nothing happens, if I open Disk Utility I can see the DMG was recognized but not mounted, and if I click on Mount I get

`Could not mount "Anki". (com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter error -119930872)`

I tried to do it from the command line too with `hdiutil`

```
sudo hdiutil attach -verbose ~/Downloads/anki-2.1.54-mac-intel-qt6.dmg
Initialising…
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CEncryptedEncoding
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      900, CUDIFEncoding
DIFileEncodingNewWithBackingStore: CUDIFEncoding
DIFileEncodingNewWithBackingStore: instantiator returned 0
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CSegmentedUDIFEncoding
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CSegmentedUDIFRawEncoding
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score     1000, CUDIFDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score        0, CSparseBundleDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score        0, CSparseDiskImage
CRawDiskImage: data fork length 0x0000000009F6F521 (167179553) not a multiple of 512.
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score     -100, CRawDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score     -100, CShadowedDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  6, score     -100, CWrappedDiskImage
DIDiskImageNewWithBackingStore: CUDIFDiskImage
DIDiskImageNewWithBackingStore: instantiator returned 0
Verifying…
Verification completed…
Error 0 (Undefined error: 0).
expected CRC32 $5FC1C39E
Attaching…
DI_kextWaitQuiet: about to call IOServiceWaitQuiet...
DI_kextWaitQuiet: IOServiceWaitQuiet took 0.000003 seconds
2022-08-30 12:46:50.023 diskimages-helper[5854:31228] DIHelperHDID serveImage: attaching drive
{
    autodiskmount = 1;
    "hdiagent-drive-identifier" = "A2D05E35-EBDB-4E7F-826B-C916C60188D1";
    "unmount-timeout" = 0;
}
2022-08-30 12:46:50.025 diskimages-helper[5854:31228] DIHelperHDID serveImage: connecting to myDrive 0x370B
2022-08-30 12:46:50.025 diskimages-helper[5854:31228] DIHelperHDID serveImage: register _readBuffer 0x7ff410650000
2022-08-30 12:46:50.025 diskimages-helper[5854:31228] DIHelperHDID serveImage: activating drive port 18187
2022-08-30 12:46:50.025 diskimages-helper[5854:31228] DIHelperHDID serveImage: set cache enabled=TRUE returned SUCCESS.
2022-08-30 12:46:50.025 diskimages-helper[5854:31228] DIHelperHDID serveImage: set on IO thread=TRUE returned SUCCESS.
2022-08-30 12:46:50.025 diskimages-helper[5854:31228] -processKernelRequest: will sleep received
Mounting…
2022-08-30 12:46:50.089 diskimages-helper[5854:31224] -remountReturningDictionary: detaching because no mountable filesystems.
Attaching…
Error 112 (no mountable file systems).
Finishing…
DIHLDiskImageAttach() returned 112
hdiutil: attach failed - no mountable file systems
```

I also tried to reset the SMC and I got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I "solved" this problem by restarting the mac until it work, I had to restart 3 times (not counting the SMC restart).

I don't know if there is a more permanent fix, but keep restarting and it will eventually work (at least that worked for me)